# Excel: VLookup with missing data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to do a vlookup to pull in pricing info from one table based on dates.  Problem is, the table that contains the pricing info does not have records for every single date.  In these scenarios, I want to pull back the price from the last available "effective date".  For example, cell B2 would return a value of $448.48 since there is no exact match for "1/1/2015".

[image]

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwos4.png):

Comment: I tried/researched using vlookup in conjuction with IF statement but with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:
`=VLOOKUP(A2,$G$2:$H$16,2,TRUE)`

$G$2:$H$16 is the Table with price (Effective Date, Price_File_Avg) change it to correspond your references
Keep the $ for fixed references when you drag the formula down the column
A2 is the date that you want to find the corresponding price
2 is the second column (price) in the Table with price
True will find the nearest value if no exact match
The Table with price_File_Avg should be sorted by Effective Date oldest to newest

[image]

Comment: Thanks yass but I tried that already and it does not work.

Comment: When you write True it will find the nearest Date and your Data have to be sorted like I explained

Comment: @D.Vo It works as I think you want it here.  What errors are you coming up with?

Answer (score 1):

Another method is using `INDEX MATCH`

```
=INDEX($I$1:$I$31, MATCH(A1, $G$1:$G$31, 1))
```

`$I$1:$I$31` is your reference to **Price** range
`$G$1:$G$31` is your reference to **Effective Date** range

The third parameter of `MATCH` has three possible values:

```
 1 for less than value
 0 for exact match
-1 for greater than value
```

Hence we use value `1` rather than the usual `0` for exact match.

Comment: Thanks Vylix but you are close but not 100%.  My apologies but I should also clarify that in the event of an exact match, I want that value.  If no exact match, pull value from last available date.  I uploaded another image.  Using your method, i got the values in column E.  Column F shows what the values should be.  Column G shows the date of the value found in column F.  Column H is just a brief explanation as to why column F is correct.

Comment: @D.Vo I'm not sure why your data failed to lookup properly. Please double check if the proper formula was inserted. You might forgot to put `$` on one of the ranges? I tried with your data, and it turned out to be correct : https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtocr.png

Comment: I think I see what the problem is, for whatever reason it's ignoring the year